# David Zindell's Neverness setting: What is a 'Tubist?'

Tags: neverness

David Zindell's *Neverness* setting uses a lot of obscure and foreign language words to evoke the feel of the setting.  While nowhere near as obscure or dense as Gene Wolfe, there is still at least one word whose usage or derivation I don't fully understand:  "Tubist."

It's used most often in conjuction with "Thingist."
Some examples:

> I was so shocked that I spilled coffee on my lap, burning my leg. The
>   Merchant Pilots of Tria - those wily, unethical thingists and tubists -
>   for a long time had tried to break the power of our Order. "What
>   are you saying, Mother? That we should be traitors?"

And:

> He pointed to the pieces of the mug scattered across the table. "I
>   must factor in my advertising costs.  They blow these mugs on Fostora,
>   and you must know, it was precious."
>
> I pounded the table with the edge of my fist and felt porcelain crumbs
>   grinding into thin leather of my glove. "You're a filthy, greedy
>   tubist," I said.
>
> He looked at me quickly as his nostrils opened and closed. "A tubist,
>   you call me. Yes, it's true, I serve myself, and why not? I used to
>   serve my God, but He betrayed me." He pointed to the tondo and at the
>   case of priceless Darghinni jewelry standing next to it. "Now I
>   collect things. Things do not betray."
>
> "Too many things," I said. "You're a thingist *and* a tubist."

"Thingist," in context is easily deciphered as a person (in a somewhat ascetic post-scarcity environment) as someone who is too attached to physical things and material wealth.  Not exactly cryptic.

"Tubist," seems to be adjacent (it's certainly not someone who plays a tuba) but the second quote makes clear that there's some distinction between the two terms, and I have no idea what it is.

Does anyone know what Zindell is driving at here?  What "tubist," means and what the origin of the term is, in the sense he's using it?

Comment: *And from cave-Men at last arose Man, and Man, who was at once clever and stupid took to bed four wives: The Bomb; The Computer; The Test Tube; and Woman.*

Comment: @Valorum That is an angle I had not considered, but even making that connection I'm not sure what it *means*.

Comment: I've twitted at the author and dropped them an email. Hopefully we'll get a direct response.

Comment: From the sequels "*You say that the people of Neverness are cut off from life, but you haven't journeyed to Tria, where the tubists and merchants spend almost their entire lives inside plastic boxes breathing conditioned air and facing sense boxes*"

Comment: I thought the context made it obvious. They basically say it. A tubist is someone who cares too much about themself. Someone who is dedicated to seeking their own benefit and pleasure, probably with an emphasis on pleasures of the senses. It must come from what Valorum mentioned: the tubist focuses on what comes from a test tube, i.e. their own body.

Comment: @Adamant - It doesn't *seem* obvious.

Comment: @Valorum - But they literally restate it as a definition: "A tubist, you call me. **Yes, it's true, I serve myself, and why not**?"

Comment: @Adamant - the way I read it, OP isn't looking for a *broad definition*. They're looking for an etymology and a close definition

Comment: @valorum That is correct.  A fictional etymology if necessary, but some in-universe understanding of the origin of the term.

Comment: @Adamant for reasons that go well outside the scope of stack-comments, while the term may be related to the quote Valorum provides, I am unconvinced.

Comment: Those reasons should probably be included in the question, if they won't fit in comments.

Comment: @Adamant - Well, it turns out that it was *one* of the ideas I had.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My good friend David Zindell was kind enough to explain both the meaning and etymology of this word in an email (which I'm sure he won't mind me quoting from). In short, the concept is that the digestive system is a tube. 'Tubists' are obsessed with what goes into and what comes out of their bodies.

> Tubist is dig at excessively selfish, materialistic people, in
>   particular people whose life centers around satisfying the baser
>   passions, like eating, the idea being that food goes in one end and
>   out the other of a tube.

He also mentioned that you can get a free copy of [*Shanidar And Other Stories*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/51378214-shanidar-and-other-stories) to those who [sign up for his newsletter](https://www.davidzindell.com/free-book/).

Comment: That is absolutely fantastic, thank you.  It makes perfect sense in retrospect, and yet I would not have figured it out.  And @adamant was correct on the meaning, but off on the etymology, so to speak.